# Material-UI Auto Complete won't Select on Left Click

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a working Material-UI Auto Complete I can search for values I can select items with the arrow keys on the keyboard and I can pick an item with the return key. If I click an item with the mouse the suggestions just disappear and nothing gets selected. I been researching this issue for a while and I can't find anyone that has resolved it. The code examples on the official Material-UI website have the same issue you can't select the items with the mouse.

```
import React from 'react';

import AutoComplete from 'material-ui/lib/auto-complete';

var sampleFacilities = require('../sample-facility');

var NewOutbreakForm = React.createClass({

  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      facilities: [],
      facility: ''
    }
  },

  componentDidMount: function() {
    this.setState({ facilities: sampleFacilities, facility: '' });
  },

  selectedItem: function(chosenRequest, index) {
    this.setState({ facility: chosenRequest });
  },

  render: function() {

    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="panel panel-default">
          <div className="panel-heading">
              <h3 className="panel-title">New Outbreak</h3>
          </div>
          <div className="panel-body">

            <div className="row">
              <did className="col-md-6">
                <AutoComplete floatingLabelText="Facility Name" onNewRequest={this.selectedItem} searchText={this.state.facility} dataSource={this.state.facilities} filter={AutoComplete.caseInsensitiveFilter} maxSearchResults={5} />
              </did>
              <did className="col-md-6">
              </did>
            </div>

          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    );
  }
});

export default NewOutbreakForm;
```

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be an issue with v0.15.0-alpha.1 version v0.14.4 works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

This problem has now been solved in version 0.15.0-alpha.2.

https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/issues/3566